# How do you share plans with your clients?

Tags: planning

I have a simple question: which media do you use to send plans to your clients?

We have built an internal tool for that but I am sure there are more efficient way to proceed.

Comment: How do you share *planning*(verb), or how do you share *plans"(noun)?

Comment: Indeed, I should have been more specific, how do you share gantt chart?

Comment: Do you mean "plans" or reports, i.e., actual performance compared to your plans?  If plans, the media to use is the media in which you developed the plans.

Comment: I am not sure how a list of media that would result from this question being answered properly would help you determine efficiency.  There are a lot of processes before something is delivered to a client.  One person's efficient media might be another's nightmare, depending on process maturity and other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Barani about the level of detail: before sharing something with client be sure you realized what kind of information client is interested in (Milestones, Deliverables, ...) and then define an effective format (graphs maybe).

Moreover consider the reason why you are sharing: do you want the client to be aware of any critical situation? Do you need any feedback by the client?

If the latter should be involved in the decision process, be sure to share all the necessary details as well as the (short, mid, long term) estimated outcomes

Comment: I am mostly working on short term (~2 to 3 months) digital projects, on which lot of iterations and feedback from the client are required. Sharing the plan is the way to highlight the period when the client will have to be available.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what level of detail that you want to share from your plan and also your communication plan (status communication, frequency) & stakeholder level that you are targeting.

Plan that is created for running project will have detail end-to-end, whereas client may not be interested in all details.

Better would be to convert your internal tool values to Excel, convert them to pictorial representation of the progress and highlighted plan for coming period.

If this is not part of your regular plan updates, share Milestones that client is interested in (areas that would impact client)